# What's the fastest way to create an API over a RESTful JSON interface for MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

My technical experise is restricted to **Javascript** and **Python**.

How can I create an API for MongoDb that I may use with my client side Javascript MVC framework?

Comment: Would you prefer using Python or JavaScript on the server-side?

Comment: I would prefer using Python

Comment: Are you already familiar with some Python web framework like Django or Flask?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with Django

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working with Django I'd recommend a stack consisting of an API library plus a decent MongoDB schema layer (if necessary).

For instance:

- Define your models with MongoEngine (http://mongoengine.org/)
- Structure your API with Django-tastypie (https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie)

That being said, I feel like MongoDB is not a perfect match for Django. Django provides a lot of facilities like database syncing, which is set in place to work around the very same issues NoSQL databases readily solve.

Some of the extra features that Django provides, like Admin UI, may not even work out-of-the-box with NoSQL. I'm aware there is Django-nonrel which is trying to bridge this gap (https://github.com/django-nonrel), but to be honest, I'm not sure if its very stable or if its still being developed.

A little more approachable alternative might be to simply use Flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/) with MongoEngine andFlask-RESTful (https://github.com/twilio/flask-restful).

A proof-of-concept structure for such application:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext import restful
from mongoengine import connect, Document

# MongoEngine model
class User(Document):
    email = StringField(required=True)

app = Flask(__name__)
api = restful.Api(app)
connect('yourdb') # connect to Mongo

class MyAPI(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        return User.objects

api.add_resource(MyAPI, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question though, how do I configure Flask to work on my Apache ModWsgi setup?

Comment: @ZachWild check out the documentation here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/ although I gotta say I personally prefer gunicorn whenever possible: http://gunicorn.org/